# How to get the duplicate rows based on the 95% criteria in Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

For example I have a data frame with 70 columns and want to get the duplicate records(rows) with 95% match.
To get 100% match we can use duplicated() but in order to get duplicate match with 95% threshold what need to be done.

**Sample Dataset:**
[image]
In above dataset there are 16 columns out of which if 15(95%) are same then it should return it as Duplicate.

**Output Dataset:**
output dataset will have 1st, 3rd and 4th row as duplicate as 1st and 4th are 100% matching and 3rd is 95%(15th columns values) matching. 2nd row will not be there in output as criteria for 95% is not matching.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: What is your code, expected result?

Comment: Please define your input dataframe (all numeric?) and how do you define a 95% match

Comment: Ideally provide a sample dataset and the matching expected output

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.